# total confusion with Bootstrap and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, header

Done this a whole bunch of times, but now it's acting out for some reason. Though I'll probably feel very dumb, after somebody points out the mistake.
Live link: 
http://soloveich.com/project6

I'm trying to build a header, but getting quite a few problems at the same time

1) Background images for class header and #soc don't show
2) that image with large text does not align to center
3) I get the post on the right side of the header, while it has to be under it.
css is properly connected (tried changing body background color)
header code

```
<div class="header">
    <header>
       <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-lg-3"><div class="pull-right"><a href="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>"><img src="wp-content/themes/greendream/images/logo.png"></a>    </div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6"><div id="text"><img src="wp-content/themes/greendream/images/text.png"></div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3"><div id="soc"></div></div>
       </div>

    </header>
</div>
```

css

```
.header {
background-image: url(images/hdbg.jpg);
}

#text {
width: 578px;
margin:o auto;
}

#soc {
background-image: url(images/soc.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start by studying how the [grid system in Bootstrap 3 works](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Basically, if you want your content centered, you need to place it in a container.  Then you set up your rows and columns.

Something like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>"><img src="wp-content/themes/greendream/images/logo.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="wp-content/themes/greendream/images/text.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Note:  There is no `row-fluid` in Bootstrap 3.  A lot of what you're trying to do will only work in Bootstrap 2.